# Ubuntu/opt directory permission denied issue

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, gedit, bashrc

Ubuntu Newbie here!

I am currently trying to install OpenFoam 10 in my machine, and need to edit the bashrc file located in Ubuntu/opt/openfoam/etc. Anytime I try to manually open the file and edit it I get this error:

Failed to save document#

Error opening file "opt.openfoam10/etc/bashrc": permission denied

I also tried to use the sudo gedit command to access the file and get this other error from the terminal:

sudo gedit ~./bashrc
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified

However, when I look at the permission in the folder, /opt directory has drwxr-wr-x, so it seems like my user does not have 'root' permissions?
I feel I might be missing some simple setting but can't seem to find what it is.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest using a CLI editor with sudo - you could use `sudoedit /opt/openfoam/etc/bashrc` or specify a particular editor like `sudo nano /opt/openfoam/etc/bashrc`

Comment: Try "sudo -E gedit file"

Comment: @steeldriver your method worked perfectly, thanks so much!